# dmcache - is removing cache device without suspending safe?

Tags: storage, cache, ssd, unmount, device-mapper

I'm using plain dmcache for SSD cache - unmount procedure goes this way:

```
umount fs
suspend cache device
remove cache device
close lvm
close LUKS
shutdown
```

However sometimes dmsetup doesn't allow me to remove cache device throwing `Device busy` error, even if everything is synced before `umount`. Usual "fix" is to not suspend cache, sync everything and remove active cache device - but is it safe? Or can it result in data corruption?